# Get JSON value to Array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I need to get the JSON value from MYSQL and display it in the table view. I have done PHP part to receive data but I have error with my XCODE. My data will store temperature, humidity and digital status (on off) of sensor. I have questions below:

1. How to get ON/OFF JSON value and store in Bool array?
2. How to get JSON value and store in Float array?
3. if JSON value is , how can I store value as 0 in XCODE?

---

```
class DataManager {
  var nodenameArray: [String] = []
  var nodeidArray: [String] = []
  var tempArray: [Float] = []
  var humArray: [Float] = []
  var pirArray: [Bool] = []
  var lightArray: [Bool] = []
  var relayArray: [Bool] = []
  var hallArray: [Bool] = []
  var smokeArray: [Bool] = []

  @objc func taskdo() {
    self.nodenameArray = []
    self.nodeidArray = []
    self.tempArray = []
    self.humArray = []
    self.pirArray = []
    self.lightArray = []
    self.relayArray = []
    self.hallArray = []
    self.smokeArray = []

    if userlogin == true {
      let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: http://talectric.com/wp-admin/a_p/iot/read_all.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)&authen=wdwfesf9329140dsvfxkciospdkm"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error!)")
                return
            } else {
                do {
                    if let respondString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                        print(respondString)
                        if let nodedata = respondString.value(forKey: "nodedata") as? NSArray {
                            for node in nodedata{
                                if let nodeDict = node as? NSDictionary {
                                    if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "node_id") {
                                        self.nodeidArray.insert(nodeid as! String, at: 0)
                                    }
                                    if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "node_name") {
                                        self.nodenameArray.insert(nodeid as! String, at: 0)
                                    }
                                    if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "temp") {
                                        self.tempArray.insert(Float(nodeid as! String)!, at: 0)
                                    }
                                    if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "hum") {
                                       print(nodeid)
                                        self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0)                
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    print(self.nodenameArray)
                    print(self.nodeidArray)
                    print(self.tempArray)
                    print(self.humArray)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
  }
}
```

below is the respond:

```
{
    nodedata =     (
            {

        "hall_status" = "<null>";

        hum = 111;

        "light_status" = "<null>";

        "node_id" = y2cfwecrw3hqznuxmfvf;

        "node_name" = SVIN03;

        "pir_status" = OFF;
        "relay_status" = "<null>";
        "smoke_status" = "<null>";
        temp = 2132;
    },
            {
        "node_name" = SVIN04;
        nodeid = aj2w1aljw8nd65ax79dm;
    },
            {
        "hall_status" = "<null>";
        hum = 100;
        "light_status" = "<null>";
        "node_id" = mwmfl2og2l8888fjpj2d;
        "node_name" = SVIN05;
        "pir_status" = ON;
        "relay_status" = "<null>";
        "smoke_status" = "<null>";
        temp = 45;
    }
);
numberofnodeid = 3;
}
```

111
100

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568).
>   2018-10-11 08:11:05.352491+0700 IOT 2[1506:101847] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568).

error is in this line :

`self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0)`

Comment: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568).` + Line `self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0)` suggests that `nodeid` is a `NSNumber` not a `String`, because `nodeDict.value(forKey: "temp")` is not a `String`.

Comment: In a general way: Avoid using force unwrap (using `!`). Don't use all theses arrays to have synced values. Instead use a Custom Struct/Class, Codable also in Swift 4 could be an interesting idea to use. Don't use NSStuff in Swift3+ when there is equivalent in Swift: `NSMutableURLRequest` => `URLRequest` (that will also avoid the `as URLRequest` later, `NSURL` => `URL`...

Comment: You are getting `temp` and `hum` as Int so use `NSNumber` rather than `NSString` as `self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! NSNumber)!), at: 0)` for above parameter

Comment: @Larme you mean that i should not use this code, right ?
if let nodedata = respondString.value(forKey: "nodedata") as? NSArray {

                        for node in nodedata{

                            if let nodeDict = node as? NSDictionary {

                                if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "node_id"){
                                    self.nodeidArray.insert(nodeid as! String, at: 0)
                                }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to look at json_decode to read data from json in php

Example:

```
`$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // this will print 12345`
```

How to get ON/OFF JSON value and store in Bool array ?
basically you have to add a new value to your onOff variable, something like

```
$onOff=array();
$val;
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (is_null($obj->{'name_of_the_alert'})) {
   $val = 0
} else {
   $val = $obj->{'name_of_the_alert'};
}
array_push($onOff,$obj->{'name_of_the_alert'});
```

How to get JSON value and store in Float array ?
Basically same thing, I haven't use PHP in a while, but just declare the array of the value type you need.

if JSON value is , how can i store value as 0 in XCODE ?
 I guess you mean if it is null, in this case you have to do this

```
$onOff=array();
$val;
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (is_null($obj->{'name_of_the_alert'})) {
   $val = 0
} else {
   $val = $obj->{'name_of_the_alert'};
}
array_push($onOff,$obj->{'name_of_the_alert'});
```

Take into consideration that I may have some mistakes here because I am not familiar with newer PHP versions.

Good luck

Comment: when i use  self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0) to store Float value ( String receive from JSON and convert to Float), i create error Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568). 2018-10-11 08:11:05.352491+0700 IOT 2[1506:101847] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568).

Comment: In this case, I would first print the nodeid as! String to screen to make sure what are we getting, maybe there's something else in that screen and that's why you cannot convert it just like that, because it should work.
maybe there's a C or F in the string and you need to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is clear that `temp` and `hum` are Number type(Int of Double). So use `NSNumber` rather than `NSString` as:

```
self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! NSNumber)!), at: 0)
```

As more swifty approach, you can update your code as:

```
if let nodeDict = node as? [String: Any] {
    if let nodeid = nodeDict["node_id"] as? String {
        self.nodeidArray.insert(nodeid, at: 0)
    }
    if let nodename = nodeDict["node_name"] as? String {
        self.nodenameArray.insert(nodename, at: 0)
    }
    if let temp = nodeDict["temp"] as? Int {
        self.tempArray.insert(Float(temp), at: 0)
    }
    if let hum = nodeDict["hum"] as? Int {
        self.humArray.insert(Float(hum), at: 0)                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of issues with your code:

First, avoid using NSStuff in Swift3+ when there is the equivalent.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: http://talectric.com/wp-admin/a_p/iot/read_all.php")! as URL)
...
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
```

=>

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: http://talectric.com/wp-admin/a_p/iot/read_all.php")!)
...
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
```

See, you avoid already all the `as URL`, `as URLRequest`.

Avoid force unwrapping: Avoid using `!`.
Because if it's nil or with `as!` the cast fails (and then it's nil), you'll get a crash.
Use `if let`, `guard let`. [Read this about Optional](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)

As a sample, I would have wrote:

```
guard let url = URL(string:http...) else {
    print("invalid URL")
    return
}
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
```

Parsing part:

```
if let respondString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
```

Get rid of `NSDictionary`, use `[String: Any]` instead, then get rid of `.allowFragments`, it's rarely useful (it makes sense on certains cases only) don't use the force unwrap on `data!`, and don't name your variable `respondString`
 because that's clearly not a `String` and that's clearly misleading.

=>

```
guard let data = data else { return }
if let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
```

Now:

```
if let nodedata = respondString.value(forKey: "nodedata") as? NSArray {
    for node in nodedata{
        if let nodeDict = node as? NSDictionary {
            if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "node_id") {
                self.nodeidArray.insert(nodeid as! String, at: 0)
            }
            if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "node_name") {
                self.nodenameArray.insert(nodeid as! String, at: 0)
            }
            if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "temp") {
                self.tempArray.insert(Float(nodeid as! String)!, at: 0)
            }
            if let nodeid = nodeDict.value(forKey: "hum") {
               print(nodeid)
                self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0)                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No, no `NSArray`, no `NSDictionary`, avoid using `value(forKey:)` because it does what you think it does on a `NSDictionary` doing a `object(forKey:)`, or simply subscript (using `["someKey"]`) but on an `Array` you'll get an issue with an unexpected result I think.
Don't name all your var `nodeid`, it's harder to debug after ward, don't do a soft unwrap (`if let`) if just afterward you do a force unwrap on that value.

```
if let nodedata = responseDict["nodedata"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    for aNode in nodedata {
        if let id = aNode["node_id"] as? String {
            self.nodeidArray.insert(nodeId, at: 0)
        }
        if let name = aNode["node_name"] as? String {
            self.nodenameArray.insert(name, at: 0)
        }
        if let temp = aNode["temp"] as? String, let tempFloat = Float(temp) {
            self.tempArray.insert(tempFloat, at: 0)
        }
        if let hum = aNode["hum"] as? String, let humFloat = Float(hum) {
            self.humArray.insert(humFloat, at: 0)                
        }
    }
}
```

That's much more readable.

Now instead of using `insert(_:at:)`, it might be easier to use `nodedata.inverted()`.

Now, let's talk about architecture:
What happens in your case, if you don't pass the `if let hum = aNode["hum"] as? String, let humFloat = Float(hum) {` on one iteration (let's say the second one which is exactly your case in the sample you gave there is no `temp`) but success on all the others? 
Here what's going to happen:
`self.nodeidArray[3]` and `self.humArray[3]` won't be correct, they'll be desynchronized, right?
Because `self.nodeidArray[2]` should be with `self.humArray[1]`.

Theses values are meant to be synce'd, so use a custom Struct/Class for it:
After all, Swift is a OOP (Object Oriented Programming) language, so use objects.

```
struct Node {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let humidity: Float?
    let temperature: Float?
}
```

So instead of having:

```
var nodenameArray: [String] = []
var nodeidArray: [String] = []
var tempArray: [Float] = []
var humArray: [Float] = []
```

Just have:

```
var nodes: [Node] = []
```

And during the parsing, do

```
let node = Node.init(withDict: aNode)
nodes.append(node) //or insert it at 0
```

You can construct your own method `init` in Node, let's say:

```
func init(withDict dict: [String: Any]) {
    if let id = dict["node_id"] as? String {
        self.id = id
    }
    etc.
}
```

Having this `Node` class simplify. But using the `JSONSerialization` and init all the values manually could be avoided using [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) (available in Swift 4).

Side Note:

This code is not tested, there might be some glitch, typo etc. Let's focus on the explanation instead.

Lastly concerning the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10db6f878) to
>   'NSString' (0x10ca71568). 2018-10-11 08:11:05.352491+0700 IOT
>   2[1506:101847] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber'
>   (0x10db6f878) to 'NSString' (0x10ca71568).
>
> error is in this line :
>
> `self.humArray.insert(Float(Int(nodeid as! String)!), at: 0)`

The error means that at some point you tried to cas (using `as`) on a  a `(NS)String`, but is was in fact `NSNumber` (in Swift, it's easily converted into an `Int`/`Float`, etc.), so it failed.
So the part that failed: `nodeid as! String`, because `nodeid` is not a `(NS)String`

Comment: I create struct
struct Node: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var humidity: Float?
    var temperature: Float?
    init(withDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        if let id = dict["node_id"] as? String {
            self.id = id
        }
        if let name = dict["node_name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }
        if let humidity = dict["hum"] as? Float {
            self.humidity = humidity
        }
        if let temperature = dict["tem"] as? Float {
            self.temperature = temperature
        }
    }
}

Comment: this struct is created without error. Parsing also follow your suggest 
if let nodedata = responseDict["nodedata"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                                for aNode in nodedata {
                                    let node = Node.init(withDict: aNode)
                                    self.nodes.append(node) //or insert it at 0

Comment: but how can I access to id element for example ?
                        print(nodes.id) // this code create error : Value of type '[Node]' has no member 'id'

Comment: class DataManager {
    var nodes: [Node] = [].   please help me to access nodes element in class Datamanager.

Comment: That's for what a `UITableView`? `nodes.id` doesn't make sense because `nodes` is an array, it you want the first it's `nodes[0].id`, the second one `nodes[1].id`, etc, or more explicitly: `let firstNode: Node = nodes[0], let firstNodeId = firstNode.id`